# Room DB - support custom collation (ICU lib)

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, android-room, collation

How can I support ICU lib collations in ROOM sql queries?
Default collation rules predefined in room are not suitable, as we have case insensitive german localization on the server side API which can not be changed and we need to return data from our database in the same order, so we have to use something like

```
ORDER BY name COLLATE "de_DE"
```

But it doesn't work, because Room doesn't have needed collation sequence (we got `SQLiteException: no such collation sequence: de_DE (code 1)`)

I know there is a way to modify SQLite code by recompiling it with ICU extension, like described [here](https://www.sqlite.org/src/artifact?ci=trunk&filename=ext/icu/README.txt). But I can not find a way to compile it for Room. Is there a way to support custom collation rules in Room DB?

Comment: AFAIK, you would need to have your own copy of SQLite, plus the `SupportSQLite*` classes tied to that copy of SQLite. I have done that with [SafeRoom](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-saferoom) and SQLCipher for Android, though I don't know if SQLCipher for Android has the ICU extensions or not. You might also see if [Requery's SQLite](https://github.com/requery/sqlite-android) has what you need.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks for reply! Now we are trying to compile custom sqllite, because we understood that we also need sqlchipher in our project. Seems, proposed solution is the one and only way to make it work with ICU.

Comment: @A.Shevchuk I have the same problem, did you solve it somehow?
I'm trying to enable icu on sqlcipher, but I'm failing.